# I have a scientific paper on gravity, how do I publish it, and will my research benefit me?

Tags: galaxy, gravity, cosmology, light, jupiter

I read a lot about gravity and discovered a hole in it, and I want to publish that hole, but I am not good at mathematics. To show that gap, what should I do? Should I use Newton's equations which are easy in my research, or fight and read about Einstein's equations which are very difficult

Comment: Well, given that Newton's laws are only an approximation, yeah, you'd have to use Einstein.

Comment: The title and body of the question appear to be about different things.

Comment: As posed, I am not really sure this is an astronomy question.  It also isn't specific enough for us to recommend the use of Newton's or Einstein's equations.

Comment: Unless we know what the "gap" is we can't answer this question.  The blunt truth is that unless you have a deep and mathematical understanding of Einstein's General Relativity, you haven't discovered anything at all.

Comment: You can benefit emotionally from having your knowledge shared.  But unless you have a way to engineer something to sell, you aren't going to benefit financially from your discovery.  Authors of articles don't get paid (which is why so much of science is "filling out grant applications")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about astronomy. That said, I'd recommend taking a look at [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/35515) on Academia Stack Exchange, which has some points you may want to consider.

Comment: This meta post in Math SE is not the same thing, but some advice there may also be helpful [$\pi \ + \ e$ is irrational, I want to share but nervous.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33323/284619) But as mentioned the Academia SE site is the best place for questions about how to proceed with research and there are plenty of science folks there. I'd say start by looking around at related questions; the example HDE226868 mentions is a great one but you can probably find more after that as well.

Comment: Newton's theory of gravity is a very good approximation, unless you're dealing with high energy situations, like orbits around neutron stars. If you think you've found a gap or hole that applies even in the low energy regime, then it's *probably* the case that you've made a mistake, or misunderstand what the standard theory says.

Comment: (cont) If you have a question about Newtonian gravity, you can ask it on the Physics Stack Exchange (after first checking that it hasn't been asked already). Note that asking people to check a personal theory which contradicts mainstream physics is off-topic on that site. However, if something in the mainstream theory *seems* contradictory to you, then it's fine to ask about that.